# Efficient Way to Evaluate the Proximal Operator of $ f \left( x \right) = {\left\| x \right\|}_{2} + {I}_{\geq 0} \left( x \right) $

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, proximal-operators

Is there an efficient way to evaluate the proximal operator of the function $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R \cup \{ \infty \}$ defined by
\begin{equation}
f(x) = \| x \|_2 + I_{\geq 0}(x),
\end{equation}
where $I_{\geq 0}$ is the indicator function of the nonnegative orthant:
\begin{equation}
I_{\geq 0}(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \quad \text{if } x \geq 0,\\
\infty & \quad \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
(The inequality $x \geq 0$ is interpreted componentwise.)

In other words, given $\hat x \in \mathbb R^n$, is there an easy way to solve the optimization problem
\begin{align}
\text{minimize} & \quad \|x\|_2 + \frac{1}{2} \| x - \hat x \|_2^2 \\
\text{subject to} & \quad x \geq 0.
\end{align}
The variable in this optimization problem is $x \in \mathbb R^n$.
Ideally I'd like a closed-form solution to this optimization problem, or else a way to compute the solution extremely quickly (without having to rely on an iterative algorithm).

Thoughts: the term $\| x \|_2$ doesn't depend on the direction of $x$.  If not for the nonnegativity constraints on $x$, we would pick $x$ to point in the same direction as $\hat x$, which simplifies the optimization problem enough that we can now solve it easily.  Perhaps there's a similar way to think about the problem when we have nonnegativity constraints on $x$.

Comment: http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/236C/lectures/proxop.pdf slide 9 looks promising!

Comment: @whyyes Thank you, but while those notes give the prox-operator of the 2-norm (on slide 9-3), I don't think they show how to compute this prox-operator (where $ x $ is constrained to the nonnegative orthant).

Comment: no it's the prox of $f(x) = \|x\|_2+I_c(x)$, so you can take $c$ to be the nonnegative orthant. (I think?)

Comment: oh wait I misread that, nevermind

Comment: There's a closed-form solution for the weighted sum of $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ norms. Interesting that there would not be here.

Comment: Ooh, I think we can get a closed form here. Stay tuned.

Comment: Bingo! I did it. Take a look

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I have found is that looking at the dual problem with a custom prox function is almost always helpful. To derive it, I first rewrite the problem as follows:
\begin{array}{ll}
\text{minimize}   & \tfrac{1}{2} \| x - \hat{x} \|_2^2 + t \\
\text{subject to} & \| x \|_2 \leq t \\ & x \succeq 0 
\end{array}
where $t$ is a new variable. To construct the dual I use a conic Lagrange multiplier $(w,s)$ for the 2-norm constraint and a multiplier $z$ for the nonnegativity constraint. The dual problem is
\begin{array}{ll}
\text{maximize} & \inf_{x,t} \tfrac{1}{2} \| x - \hat{x} \|_2^2 + t  - st - w^Tx - z^T x \\
\text{subject to} & \|w\|_2 \leq s \\ & z \succeq 0
\end{array}
Looking at the optimality conditions for $x$ and $t$ yields 
$$x=\hat{x}+w+z \quad s=1$$
This is what the dual gives me: a *template* for the structure of the solution. In this case, $x$ is the sum of the target vector $\hat{x}$, a vector with bounded norm $w$, and a nonnegative vector $z$. Sure, we're not there yet, but we're closer.

Eliminating the primal variables from the dual objective yields
$$\tfrac{1}{2}\|w+z\|_2^2 - (w+z)^T(\hat{x}+w+z) = 
-\tfrac{1}{2}\|\hat{x}+w+z\|_2^2 + \tfrac{1}{2}\|\hat{x}\|_2^2$$
So a "clean" dual of the prox function is
\begin{array}{ll}
\text{maximize} & -\tfrac{1}{2}\|\hat{x}+w+z\|_2^2 + \tfrac{1}{2}\|\hat{x}\|_2^2 \\
\text{subject to} & \|w\|_2 \leq 1 \\ & z \succeq 0
\end{array}
At this point I can almost read off the solution by inspection.

First, suppose $\hat{x}\preceq 0$. Then it should be evident that the optimal values are $x=0$, $w=0$, $z=-\hat{x}$. From now on, we can assume that at least one value of $\hat{x}$ is positive.

But in fact, we can go further. Partition $\hat{x}$, rearranging if necessary, into its positive and nonpositive components. That is,
$$\hat{x} = \begin{bmatrix} \hat{x}_+ \\ \hat{x}_- \end{bmatrix}, \quad 
\hat{x}_+\in\mathbb{R}^k_{++}, ~ \hat{x}_-\in-\mathbb{R}^{n-k}_+$$
Partition $w=(w_+,w_-)$, $z=(z_+,z_-)$, and $x=(x_+,x_-)$ in identical fashion. This partitions the full problem as follows:
\begin{array}{ll}
\text{maximize} & -\tfrac{1}{2}\|\hat{x}_++w_++z_+\|_2^2 -\tfrac{1}{2}\|\hat{x}_-+w_-+z_-\|_2^2 + \tfrac{1}{2}\|\hat{x}\|_2^2 \\
\text{subject to} & \|w_+\|_2^2 + \|w_-\|_2^2 \leq 1 \\ & z_+,z_- \succeq 0
\end{array}
The optimal values of the $-$ portion of the objective are clear:
$$z_- = -\hat{x}_-, \quad w_- = 0 \quad\Longrightarrow\quad x_- = 0$$
So in other words, *any* nonpositive element of $\hat{x}$ corresponds to a zero at the optimal solution.

Furthermore, we claim that $z_+=0$ as well. After all, since $\hat{x}_++z_+\succeq \hat{x}_+$, any nonzero value of $z_+$ would reduce the objective (to be maximized) with no other benefit. So with $z_+$ clamped to zero, we're left with a standard $\ell_2$ prox function for the positive portion of the vector! That is,
$$w_+ = \begin{cases} -\hat{x}_+ & \|\hat{x}\|_2 \leq 1 \\ -\|\hat{x}_+\|_2^{-1} \hat{x}_+ & \|\hat{x}\|_2\geq 1 \end{cases}, \quad
x_+ = \begin{cases} 0 & \|\hat{x}\|_2 \leq 1 \\ (1-\|\hat{x}_+\|_2^{-1}) \hat{x}_+ & \|\hat{x}\|_2\geq 1 \end{cases}$$

In sum: to compute this prox, clamp the negative values of $\hat{x}$ to zero, and scale the positive components according to the standard $\ell_2$ prox function. This is very similar to the $\ell_1 + \ell_2$ case: the $\ell_1$ shrinkage comes first followed by the $\ell_2$ scaling.

Answer (score 2):

Let $C$ be a nonempty closed convex set of a Hilbert space and $\gamma > 0$ (for example $C = \mathbb R^n_+$ and $\gamma =1$ in your particular case).
Then for $x \ne 0$, we have
$$\|x\|_2 \le \frac{1}{2}(\|x\|_2^2 r^{-1} + r), \forall r > 0,$$
with equality iff $r = \|x\|_2.$ 
Thus $\|x\|_2 = \min_{r > 0}\frac{1}{2}(\|x\|_2^2r^{-1} + r)$, and so
$$
\begin{split}
\min_{x \in C}\gamma \|x\|_2 + \frac{1}{2}\|x-a\|_2^2 &= \frac{1}{2}\min_{x \in C}\min_{r>0}(\gamma\|x\|_2^2r^{-1}+ \|x-a\|_2^2 + \gamma r)\\
& = \frac{1}{2}\min_{x \in C}\min_{r>0}(1 + \gamma r^{-1})\left\|x - \frac{r}{r+\gamma}a\right\|_2^2\\
&\hspace{5em}+\text{ things depending on }r\text{ alone},
\end{split}
$$
which can be solved via an alternating scheme like:
$$x^{(k+1)} = P_C\left(\frac{r^{(k)}}{{r^{(k)}+\gamma}}a\right),\;
r^{(k+1)} = \|x^{(k+1)}\|_2.$$
Using the non-expansiveness of the projection operator $P_C$, it's not hard to show that $$|r^{(k+1)} - r^{(k)}| \le \frac{\|a\|_2}{\gamma}|r^{(k)} - r^{(k-1)}|,$$ and so this alternating scheme converges exponentially fast if $\|a\|_2 < \gamma$ (this is a sufficient but not **necessary** condition).

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a simple way to look at it without using duality.
Our goal is to find the minimizer for the problem
\begin{align}
\tag{$\spadesuit$} \text{minimize} & \quad \| x \|_2 + \frac{1}{2t} \| x - \hat x \|_2^2 \\
\text{subject to} & \quad x \geq 0.
\end{align}

First note that if $\hat x_i <  0$, then there is no benefit from
taking $x_i$ to be positive.  If $x_i$ were positive, then both terms in the objective could be reduced just by setting $x_i = 0$.

It remains to select values for the other components of $x$.
This is a smaller optimization problem, with one unknown for
each positive component of $\hat x$.  The negative components
of $\hat x$ are irrelevant to the solution of this reduced problem.
Thus, we would still arrive at the same final answer if the negative
components of $\hat x$ were set equal to $0$ at the very beginning.

In other words, problem ($\spadesuit$) is equivalent to the problem
\begin{align}
\text{minimize} & \quad \| x \|_2 + \frac{1}{2t} \| x - \max(\hat x ,0)\|_2^2 \\
\text{subject to} & \quad x \geq 0,
\end{align}
which in turn is equivalent to the problem
\begin{align} \text{minimize} & \quad \| x \|_2 + \frac{1}{2t} \| x - \max(\hat x ,0)\|_2^2 
\end{align}
(because there would be no benefit from taking any component of $x$ to be negative).

This shows that $\text{prox}_{tf}(\hat x) = \text{prox}_{t \| \cdot \|_2}(\max(\hat x, 0))$.